# Different Order numbers for same patient only allows me to get one from DB

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a table called Orders.

In this table I have

ordernum

name

Everytime I add a new order it creates a new order number the name only changes if I change it... So for instance..

Donald could have 20 different orders in that table..

Now I am trying to display all the order numbers for Donald

This is my current code.

```
<?php   
    $blue =  $_SESSION['name']; // This is the customers name
    $sqll = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE name = :blah";
    $qq=$con->prepare($sqll); 
    $qq->bindparam(":blah", $blue);
    $qq->execute();
    $u=$qq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
?>
<div class="sectionContent">
    <div class="sectionFull">
        <div class="sectionOneHalf">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Orders</legend>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <label>Orders</label>
                    // Here I am trying to display all the different order numbers in teh table that are listed under his name
                     <div class="OrdersContainer">
                        <?php echo $u['ordernum'];?>
                     </div>
                </li>
            </ol>
            <br>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

Problem is, When I try to list those orders now... I only get one that shows up.

I need to display them all for that specific persons name

Comment: use `while($u=$qq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    // display orders 
} `

Comment: fetch() only returns a SINGLE row of the result set. you need a loop to fetch them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're fetching only one row from the result set. Loop through the result set to display all orders, like this:

```
while($u=$qq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    // display orders 
}
```

Your code should be like this:

```
// your code

<li>
    <label>Orders</label>

    <div class="OrdersContainer">
        <?php 
            while($u=$qq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                // display orders
                echo $u['ordernum'] . "<br />";
            } 
        ?>

    </div>
</li>

// your code
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php   
    $blue =  $_SESSION['name']; // This is the customers name
    $sqll = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE name = :blah";
    $qq=$con->prepare($sqll); 
    $qq->bindparam(":blah", $blue);
    $qq->execute();    
?>
<div class="sectionContent">
<div class="sectionFull">
    <div class="sectionOneHalf">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Orders</legend>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <label>Orders</label>
                        // Here I am trying to display all the different order numbers in teh table that are listed under his name
                        <div class="OrdersContainer">
                        <?php 
                        while($u=$qq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                        {                                      
                            echo $u['ordernum'];
                        }
                        ?>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ol>
                <br>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, your answer is fine, and i have just improved the formatting of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change fetch to fetchall should solve your problem, you appear to be fetching only a single row so thats all you will get.

Comment: so just change $qq->fetch to $qq->fetchall? when I do that I get a undefined index error now.

Comment: correct, as prateek supplied the actual code you should accept his answer. its fetchAll not fetchall

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$u=$qq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

use

```
$u=$qq->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$blue =  $_SESSION['name']; // This is the customers name
$sqll = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE name = :blah";
$qq=$con->prepare($sqll); 
$qq->bindparam(":blah", $blue);
$qq->execute();
while ($row = $qq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
// your html
echo $row['ordernum'] . "\n";
// your html
}
```

**What Change?**

Adding `while` loop